# How to create Windows store package in xamarin.UWP Application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-store-apps, xamarin.uwp

I am creating an application target three platforms 1) Android 2) iOS 3) UWP.
It works fine in all platforms in debug mode but when I try to create an application package for UWP(Store file) it gives me different error I listed below.

> Error: NUTC1056:Internal Compiler Error: 0x8000ffff. Error encountered
> while compiling method 'instance System.Void
> project.Views.ContactDetail.InitializeComponent()'.    project.UWP
>
> Error: ILT0005:
> 'C:\Users\temp.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.0.0\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe
> @"D:\Projects\project1\project\project.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\project.UWP.rsp"'
> returned exit code 1    project.UWP

I try different method like change certificate with different password and remove all nuget and than add all one by one but error is occured try to put all required image that listed as recommended .

If anyone have solution please help me.

It helps me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you this project on github ?

Comment: Yes I clone that project on Github

Comment: link ................................?

Comment: Sorry for that I am not disclose that project with any because it contains such a confidential information but please excuse for that.

Comment: okay :) okay let me check, never happened this with me , any nuget package you installed manually so i can check

Comment: I add Fluent Validation, Universal Windows ,Portable Class Library and Xamarin.Forms with all by package manager console

Comment: When you test your app in release mode, did you get the error? What is your uwp app's target version and min version? Could you try to delete the obj folder then test it again?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT Thanks For Reply my `Target version is 16299` and `Min Version is 16299`

Comment: What is the error info when you test your app in release mode?

Comment: I solve that but thank @BreezeLiu-MSFT For help In UWP project it refer Mono.
Android reference and that's why it display error. When I go through whole code I find solution